# create a named list element, if it doesnt exist already in R

Tags: r, list, null, append, subset

I have a list, `masterList`, to which i want to append another lists:, `contentList` and `contentList2`. the content lists are the result belonging to "01-response" - the first element of the `masterList`.

```
masterList <- list("01-response" = NULL, "02-response" = NULL,"03-response" = NULL,"04-response" = NULL,"05-response" = NULL)
contentList <- list(item1 = "text", item2 = "text2")
contentList2 <- list(item1 = "moretext", item2 = "moretext2")
```

I want to append `contentList` and `contentList2` to `masterList[["01-response"]]`. However, i want all the contents to be stored inside a named list inside the masterList: `masterList[["01-response"]][["contents"]], like:

```
masterList
$`01-response`
$`01-response`$content
$`01-response`$content$item1
[1] "text"

$`01-response`$content$item2
[1] "text2"

$`01-response`$content$item1
[1] "moretext"

$`01-response`$content$item2
[1] "moretext2"



$`02-response`
NULL

$`03-response`
NULL

$`04-response`
NULL

$`05-response`
NULL
```

The problem is with the appending. I need to check if `masterList[["01-response"]][["contents"]] exists, before i append. If it exists, i simply append. If it doesnt exist, i need to create it first.

Lets specify the element as a variable, such: `listElement <- "01-response"`. If i were to add a third list, `contentList3 <- list(item1 = "moretext3", item2 = "moretext4")`, i would simply run:

```
`listElement <- "01-response"`
    if(exists("content", where = masterList[[listElement]])){
      masterList[[listElement]][["content"]] <- append(masterList[[listElement]][["content"]],
                                                                         contentList3) 
    }else{
      masterList[[listElement]] <- append(masterList[[listElement]],
                                                      list(content = contentList3)) 
    }
```

However, this code breakes if the `masterList` is empty:

```
masterList
$`01-response`
NULL

$`02-response`
NULL

$`03-response`
NULL

$`04-response`
NULL

$`05-response`
NULL

exists("content", where = masterList[[listElement]])
Error in as.environment(where) : using 'as.environment(NULL)' is defunct
```

How can i check if "content" exists at the level of `masterList[[listElement]]`?

Note: this happens inside an function, threfore i want to remain flexible and avoid using `masterList[["01-response"]]`. I use `masterList[[listElement]]` instead, where `listElement <- "01-response"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can work without knowing if `content` exists already.

```r
masterList[["01-response"]]$content <- c(masterList[["01-response"]]$content, contentList, contentList2)
str(masterList)
# List of 5
#  $ 01-response:List of 1
#   ..$ content:List of 4
#   .. ..$ item1: chr "text"
#   .. ..$ item2: chr "text2"
#   .. ..$ item1: chr "moretext"
#   .. ..$ item2: chr "moretext2"
#  $ 02-response: NULL
#  $ 03-response: NULL
#  $ 04-response: NULL
#  $ 05-response: NULL
```

The trick of this is that `c(x, y)` will *create* if `x` is `NULL`, and *append* if `x` is a pre-existing list.

To answer one of your questions:

> *How can i check if "content" exists at the level of `masterList[[listElement]]`?*

```r
"content" %in% names(masterList[["01-response"]])
```